# Does εε = ε in formal languages?

Tags: formal-languages

For example would ∅*(ε) = εε = ε? Noting that ∅* = {ε}.

Takes this language equation:

```
X1 = ∅ + bX1 + aX2
X2 = ε + ∅X1 + ∅X2
```

Apply arden's lemma to X2.

```
X2 = ∅*(ε + ∅X1)
   = ∅*ε + ∅∅X1
   = εε + ∅∅X1
```

Does that seem right for X2 in this case?

I know it doesn't make sense to apply arden's lemma to the 2nd equation in this case but I'm trying to implement an algorithm that turns an equation system into a regex through brzozowski algebraic method.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The empty word $\epsilon$ is the neutral element for concatenation in formal languages so for any word $a$, $\epsilon a = a\epsilon = a$. Taking $a=\epsilon$, you indeed get $\epsilon \epsilon = \epsilon$.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I suppose it's the different for ∅∅ where a∅ = ∅ but ∅a = a?

Comment: @Majiick: How would $\varnothing a$ be $a$ rather than $\varnothing$? By definition $\varnothing a$ should mean $\{uv\mid u\in\varnothing, v\in\{a\}\} = \varnothing$.

Comment: If ∅ is just an empty set {} then {}{a} = a? I suppose not because having ∅ would mean there is no transition possible. Oh wait I just realized there's nothing in the empty set to multiply with. It's like 0*1 = 0.

Comment: @BillO'Haran Yeah it is.